# How to use css with jsp's

Tags: javascript, css, jsp

I have a site that I built with jsp's and I would like to implement css. I am a noob when it comes to jsp's so any help on how to implement it would be great. I know css is pretty easy and I have worked with it before in wordpress and other things, the implementation is the hard part for me.

Here a sample jsp of mine:

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="ttp.data.Physical_PackageDAO"%>
<%@page import="ttp.data.Physical_Package"%>
<%@page import="ttp.data.Conceptual_PackageDAO"%>
<%@page import="ttp.data.Conceptual_Package"%>
<%@page import="ttp.data.ProductionDAO"%>
<%@page import="ttp.data.Production"%>
<%@page import="ttp.data.VenueDAO"%>
<%@page import="ttp.data.Venue"%>
<jsp:include page="/header.jsp">
  <jsp:param name="title" value="Choose a Production" />
</jsp:include>


<script type="text/javascript">

function doAjax(responseFunc, url, parameters) {
  // create the AJAX object
  var xmlHttp = undefined;
  if (window.ActiveXObject){
    try {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (othermicrosoft){
      try {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (failed) {}
    }
  }
  if (xmlHttp == undefined && window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // If IE7+, Mozilla, Safari, etc: Use native object
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  if (xmlHttp != undefined) {
    // open the connections
    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
    // callback handler
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      // test if the response is finished coming down
      if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        // create a JS object out of the response text
            var obj = eval("(" + xmlHttp.responseText + ")");
        // call the response function
        responseFunc(obj);
      }
    }

    // create the parameter string
    // iterate the parameters array
    var parameterString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
      parameterString += (i > 0 ? "&" : "") + parameters[i][0] + "=" + encodeURI(parameters[i][1]);
    }

    // set the necessary request headers
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameterString.length);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    // send the parameters
    xmlHttp.send(parameterString);
  }
}//doAjax

function getSeats() {
  var packInput = document.getElementById("packid");
  var packid = packInput.value;
  doAjax(receiveAnswer, "ttp.actions.Sale3PackAction.action", [["packid", packid]]);
}

function receiveAnswer(response) {

  var aSeats = document.getElementById("aSeats");
  //var checks = document.getElementById("checks");
    while (aSeats.childNodes.length > 0) { // clear it out
    aSeats.removeChild(aSeats.childNodes[0]);
  }

   for (var i = 0; i < response.aSeats.length; i++) { // add the items back in

    var check = aSeats.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
    check.type = "checkbox";
    check.id = i;
    check.name = "aSeats";
    check.value = i;
    var input = aSeats.appendChild(document.createElement("text"));
    var br = aSeats.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    input.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response.aSeats[i]));    
  }
}

//function addToCart(){
//    var select = document.getElementById('aSeats');
//    var selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
//    //alert("Selected option: " + selectedOption.value);
//    //select.removeChild(selectedOption);
//    var option = document.getElementById("seat2");
//    option.appendChild(selectedOption);
//
//}
//
//function removeFromCart(){
//    var select = document.getElementById('seat2');
//    var selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
//    //alert("Selected option: " + selectedOption.value);
//    //select.removeChild(selectedOption);
//
//    var option = document.getElementById("aSeats");
//    option.appendChild(selectedOption);
//}
</script>


<% Venue v = (Venue)session.getAttribute("currentVenue"); %>
<% List<Conceptual_Package> cpList = Conceptual_PackageDAO.getInstance().getByVenue(v.getId()); %>

What Packages do you want to see?

 <form method="post" action="ttp.actions.Sale3PackAction.action">
 <select name="packid" id="packid">
     <% for (Conceptual_Package cp: cpList) { %>
    <option value="<%=cp.getId()%>"><%=cp.getName1()%></option>
    <% } %>


 </select>

    <input type="button" value="  next  " onclick="getSeats();"/>

    </form>


<!--new-->


Available Seats:

<div>

</div>

<form method="post" action="ttp.actions.finalizeSaleAction.action">

<div name="aSeats" id="aSeats">
</div>
    <br>


Customer Information:

<br>
<input name="name" value="Name">
<br>
<input name="address" value="Address">
<br>
<input name="telephone" value="Telephone">
<br>


    <input type="submit" value="  Buy Tickets  "/>

    </form>



<jsp:include page="/footer.jsp"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `header.jsp` (or wherever you generate your `<head>` element:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/your/style.css">
```

Comment: That seems relatively painless. Thanks. Any other tips or tricks I should know about?

Comment: @Eric: Specific to JSP? No idea, I've never used it. :)

Comment: @Eric: Webserver knows nothing about CSS. All it needs to do is to serve them up by URL. It's the webbrowser who needs to download them by the URL as specified in HTML `<link>` element. You are responsible for specifying the correct URL and placing the file at the correct location in the webserver. This is regardless of the view/template technology used at webserver (JSP/PHP/ASP/whatever). It's just basic HTTP/HTML knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

JSPs contain HTML snippets just like PHP files. You can include the necessary CSS files using the `link` tag or inline CSS using the `style` tag.